# Tmux crash when I press ESC in insert mode, how to fix that?

Tags: vim, tmux, tmuxinator

I use tmux 1.7 and iTerm2.

When i run Vim and go to Insert mode and then press Esc key my tmux session crashes with following message:

```
[lost server]
%
```

This have to be problem with tmux, because when I run Vim wihout vimrc it happend too.
Also I cleared tmux.conf file but wihout success.

How to handle with that error.

Comment: This question is better suited for [superuser](http://superuser.com/), but I'll add that according to [the tmux website](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) 1.6 is the latest version. If you're having trouble with edge builds it's probably better to report these sorts of things to their bug tracking system or to ask in #tmux on freenode IRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to downgrade tmux to version 1.6. Now this issue not occurs.

Comment: i had same issue when i installed tmux bundled with iterm2, then installed it from brew. worked for me.